# What is the difference between a complex vector of length 2 and a real vector of length 4?

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, vectors, physics

If you have two complex numbers in a vector, couldn't that be represented as a point in 4d?

Just trying to understand why quantum physics uses complex matrices instead of real matrices of double the length.

Comment: Do you know the difference between complex numbers and points in 2D?

Comment: Not really.....

Comment: Quantum mechanics in particular and physics in general uses complex numbers, because they are great for representing waves. The kludgy combination of the amplitude and the phase become a single entity. Furthermore, addition then becomes superposition of waves, and multiplication takes care of phase shifts. Works in telecommunication as well.

Comment: From a purely mathematical perspective, the difference is that complex numbers form a field, which is a 1-dimensional vector space, and you can also multiply the elements. If you look at the points on the real euclidean plane, they form a 2-dimensional vector space, but you cannot multiply them.

Comment: So in short, as real vector fields they are the same, but $\Bbb C^2$ has additional algebraic structure. This usually leads also to a semantic closeness of the real coordinates of the complex numbers in physical models using complex vector spaces as part of their state space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend checking out [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1245683/if-complex-numbers-can-be-represented-as-vectors-why-cant-we-define-2-dimens?rq=1) - it discusses the difference between vectors and scalars, and notions of multiplication and division over these objects.

In essence, complex numbers are 2-dimensional values just like 2D real-valued vectors, but the multiplication defined over them becomes particularly useful in certain contexts (i.e. quantum mechanics, among many others), and no such multiplication is generally defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I particularly enjoy the quote in pjs36's response, "Yes, we could define multiplication and division in $\mathbb{R}^2$ using $\mathbb{C}$, but it would be dishonest."